# Is using another methodology for the same question I proposed plagiarism?

Tags: plagiarism

I am not sure if the following course of actions can be considered research misconduct.

My colleagues reviewed my research plan/concept containing unpublished papers and plans in a form of written documents. They took my scientific concept, changed methodology, published a scientific paper and attracted funding. Is this misconduct considering that they took my scientific concept and employed different methodology and they did this after reviewing my written plans, not before?

Comment: How are you able to know the separate impact their review of your work had on their future outputs? For example, do you have full access to what they were working on before? It may be misconduct, but usually there isn't enough evidence to claim (or believe) that.

Comment: @Melinda: Before you further interact with this post, please take the [tour] to learn how the site works, and read the following: [I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts), [Can I answer my own question?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer), [Why we cannot evaluate your specific situation](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3406/7734).

Comment: Were you cited in their work?

Answer (score 6):

From what you've written, it seems plausible that your colleagues were also working on the scientific concept (or something similar), developed their own (similar) methodology, published a scientific paper, and attracted funding, which isn't misconduct. Establishing whether their review of your plans had any influence on their work will be difficult.